# Ansible password setup in user module. It didn't set properly

Tags: linux, ansible, digital-ocean

I'm new in ansible, I'm setting up my new instance in digitalocean for configuring new user. Basically, I have the playbook for setting up it and everythings okay when I run the playbook but when I tried to check if my password is working it didn't work.

I did the

> sudo apt-get update

to if the password is working. It didn't.

```
---
- name: Configure Server
  hosts: sample_server
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: root

  vars:
    username: sample_user
    password: sample_password

  tasks:
  - name: Update apt cache
    apt: update_cache=yes

  - name: Safe aptitude upgrade
    apt: upgrade=safe
    async: 600
    poll: 5

  - name: Add my user
    user:
      name: "{{ username }}"
      password: "{{ password }}"
      update_password: always
      shell: /bin/bash
      groups: sudo
      append: yes
      generate_ssh_key: yes
      ssh_key_bits: 2048
      state: present

  - name: Add my workstation user's public key to the new user
    authorized_key:
      user: "{{ username }}"
      key: "{{ lookup('file', 'certificates/id_rsa.pub') }}"
      state: present

  - name: Change SSH port
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: "^Port"
      line: "Port 30000"
      state: present
    # notify:
    # - Restart SSH

  - name: Remove root SSH access
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: "^PermitRootLogin"
      line: "PermitRootLogin no"
      state: present
    # notify:
    # - Restart SSH

  - name: Remove password SSH access
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
      regexp: "^PasswordAuthentication"
      line: "PasswordAuthentication no"
      state: present
    # notify:
    # - Restart SSH

  - name: Reboot the server
    service: name=ssh state=restarted

  handlers:
  - name: Restart SSH
    service: name=ssh state=restarted
```

Any idea for this. Thanks

Comment: Ansible user module needs passwords as crypted values. Do you check http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module to generate your password?

Comment: Thanks man. Got it! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible user module takes passwords as crypted values and jinja2 filters have the capability to handle the generation of encrypted passwords. You can modify your user creation task like this:

```
password: "{{ password | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: Thanks for this. Got it! :)